# PrimeFaces DataTable - Filtering (problem running the example)

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, filtering, primefaces

I am trying this example [in PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf). I understand only the first few lines of the code.

```html
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}"
    emptyMessage="No cars found with given criteria">

     <f:facet name="header">
        <p:outputPanel>
            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="carsTable.filter()" style="width:150px" />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </f:facet>
```

It could display a search box here. The reaming lines of code would be to add the column and populate the columns with data. I don't understand what

```html
<p:column filterBy="#{car.model}" 
    headerText="Model" footerText="contains"
    filterMatchMode="contains">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
</p:column>`
```

What is `#{car.model}` ? it doesn't specify anything call `model` in the java class. How do I alter my java class to make a column display?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression variable `car` is declared to be the `var` attribute of the dataTable.  This means that each unique row in the dataTable component can be referenced in expression language by the variable `car`.

The `model` property of `car` is a Bean property of the Serializable POJO Car.  It is assumed that the Car class has a property `model` meaning a getter `getModel()` and a setter `setModel()`.

The `filterBy` attribute of `<p:column>` specifies that this column header will have its own unique filter text field and that it will filter the rows on `car.model` property.

The attribute `filterMatchMode` specifies that the match criteria is `contains` which means any textual occurence of what is typed into the column filter field will equate as a matched record.  See the Primefaces Guide for a complete list of filterMatchMode options.

Comment: Well, i managed to do the same example and it doesn't filter as shown in the website. when i type the character '1' i get a totally different filter result. Has anyone come across this issue. and also i get this exception `Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: mk.war.Car`

Comment: Is this in the global filter or in the column filter where you have this problem?  Can you edit your question and add the mk.war.Car class?

Comment: It's the Car.Java class [http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/examples/trunk/prime-showcase/src/main/java/org/primefaces/examples/domain/Car.java?r=2274&spec=svn2317] that i added. This error comes when i add `<p:column filterBy="#{car.manufacturer}" headerText="Manufacturer" footerText="exact" filterOptions="#{tableBean.manufacturerOptions}" filterMatchMode="exact"> <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" /> </p:column>` code. all the other columns appear except for this. –

Answer (score 2):

```
private List<Car> carsSmall;
```

carsSmall is a list that contains `Car` objects.  `Car` is imported here:

```
import org.primefaces.examples.domain.Car;
```

[Car.java Source](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/examples/trunk/prime-showcase/src/main/java/org/primefaces/examples/domain/Car.java?r=2274&spec=svn2317)

Car is the backing bean, it has an attribute `model` that contains the car's model as a `String`.

In car  `#{car.model}`  is defined here:

```
<p:dataTable var="car"...>
```

The dataTable iterates over every element in the list `carsSmall` and you can access the current element using the name given in the `var` attribute (here: `car`). So `#{car.model}` calls the `getModel()` method of the current `Car` object.

Comment: Well, i managed to do the same example and it doesn't filter as shown in the website. when i type the character '1' i get a totally different filter result. Has anyone come across this issue. and also i get this exception Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: mk.war.Car

Comment: @Illep Primefaces randomizes the car variable in the bean. So the color will be different then yours and such, the model, year whatever all will be randomized. This means you will never get the same results as the primefaces one, unless you write them all down and add the same cars.

Comment: well, i copied the same class and didn't alter the code at all. I undestand that the values are randomly generated. but yet if i enter '19' in the 'year column', it doesn't filter out all the 'year' starting with '19'. So that's what i need to find